# generate a list of files based on a time pattern in filename

Tags: linux, bash, regex, grep

I have a camera recording device that will generate a structured folder with videos like this example below.

I want to generate a list of videos files but only those in a given time range. 
eg : between 8h00 and 17:00  (the videos outside this range have poor quality because of low light)

the file name is structured like this : [DATE Folder]AM|PM/sricam-[date]-[time]-sequence#.mp4

with the following sample ,the filter would list only the file starting at 8h08:15

```
/data/20171229AM/sricam-20171229-070814-1514520494.mp4
/data/20171229AM/sricam-20171229-073814-1514522294.mp4
/data/20171229AM/sricam-20171229-080815-1514524095.mp4
/data/20171229PM/sricam-20171229-180815-1513553225.mp4
```

i found brace expansion pattern could filter the numbers  but how doing it in all subfolders

i hope my explanations are not too confused :)

Thank you

Comment: Are the PM times really in the AM folder, too?

Comment: this was a typo as i manually edited the sample in order to have a use case without large sample. now it is fixed thanks

Answer (score 1):

After some try & error I found awk being more appropriate for doing such filtering

i came to this one line solution :

```
find $PWD -name "*.mp4" |  awk  -F- '{ if ( substr($3,1,2) <= "17" &&  substr($3,1,2) >= "08")  print $0 }'
```

but let me explain it :

```
find $PWD -name "*.mp4"   ## find all videos and print full path


awk -F-                   ## tels awk that the separator is dash character : -
```

now my output path example will be splitted  in 4 "columns"  (3 dash count) and each column is accessed throught $n

So the interesting column here is $3 because it contains the time

> $0 = /data/20171229AM/sricam-20171229-070814-1514520494.mp4
>
> $1 = /data/20171229AM/sricam
>
> $2 = 20171229
>
> $3 = 070814
>
> $4 = 514520494.mp4

we have to make a condition filtering : if the hour is between 08 and 17 then print the line.

```
substr($3,1,2)          ## take the two first chars from $3 column starting at position 1
```

> substr($3,1,2) <= "17"
>
> Note the quotes around 17 , this means "convert to string" -- without it, the two conditions in the if statement would never be true

```
print $0        ##   print the whole line (without the splitting)
```

Thank you everyone for all your suggestions .

Comment: Nice solution, @Max, and certainly more readable than mine. It could be made more idiomatic (and shorter), but that's entirely optional of course. Like this: `find -name "*.mp4" |  awk  -F- 'substr($3,1,2) >= "08" &&  substr($3,1,2) <= "17"'` as `$PWD` is the default for `find`, and `print $0` is the default action in Awk.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood what you're asking, you can combine wildcards any way you like, including matching in subdirectories. So this should do what you want: (I haven't tested it myself, though)

```
/data/*/sricam-*-{08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}????-*.mp4
```

It wasn't clear whether you wanted to exclude the videos starting from 17:00. If you need to include 17:00:00 but exlude anything after that (say), you can even combine several wildcard expressions:

```
/data/*/sricam-*-{08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}????-*.mp4 /data/*/sricam-*-170000-*.mp4
```

(Note the space between the expressions.)

Comment: I wanted videos from 08AM to 17PM   (as noted , there is a AM & PM folder for each day of recording.)
I tested the wildcard command as '**ls *-{08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}????-*.mp4**' and it filters my files but for non matching results it will display an entry like for example '**/20180201PM/*-08????-*.mp4**'
since i needed to have the full path of filename , i used the command **readlink -f *.mp4** but with find  executing recursively the readlink  command, it did  output weird results.

Comment: how can i use this wildcard expression with the find command ? the same wildcard used with ls doesn't return anything when used with : find . -name or -iname parameter .thank you

Comment: Sorry @Max, I've seen your comments only now. Didn't know that you wanted to use `find`. The combined wildcard expressions won't work with `find`. As your solution is more readable, I've upvoted yours rather than adapting mine.

Comment: Thanks @Edward  for comments & edits.. i didn't know at the beginning what was the best and easiest path to follow. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Bash wildcards will trivially solve this.  Any command which allows you to pass in multiple file name arguments will also allow you to pass in multiple wildcards.

```
printf '%s\n' 20171229AM/sricam-20171229-0[89]*.mp4 20171229AM/sricam-20171229-1[01]*.mp4 20171229PM/sricam-20171229-1[2-6]*.mp4
```

You can use the same arguments as the driver for a loop:

```
for file in 20171229AM/sricam-20171229-0[89]*.mp4 20171229AM/sricam-20171229-1[01].mp4 20171229PM/sricam-20171229-1[2-6]*.mp4; do
    : things with "$file"
done
```

Perhaps it bears pointing out that the shell (Bash, or whatever you are using) will expand the wildcards into a list of matching files before any commands are being run.  (When there are no matches, the wildcards will be passed on verbatim, though you can specify the `nullglob` option to have it simply disappear in this case.)

These are "glob" patterns, not regular expressions.  Bash has an extended globbing facility which is closer to regex, but still not exactly regex; but that is not necessary for this simple task.